# handlebar - unable to loop through data

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to apply the below model to a handlebar template to get a simple list , but I guess 
either the data hierarchy or the way I'm trying to loop through the data 
model may be incorrect.

**data.js**

```
{  
   "categories":[  
      {  
         "games":{  
            "action":{  
               "game":{  
                  "name":"Game 1",
                  "Description":"Description 1"
               },
               "game":{  
                  "name":"Game 2",
                  "Description":"Description 2"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "movies":{  
            "fantasy":{  
               "movie":{  
                  "name":"Movie 1",
                  "Description":"Description 1"
               },
               "movie":{  
                  "name":"Movie 2",
                  "Description":"Description 2"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

**template**

```
<ul id="categories">
    <li> Games 
        <ul class="subcategories">
            {{#each categories}} 
                     ...........
            {{/each}} 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to get a simple list (see below)

```
<ul id="categories">
    <li> Games 
        <ul class="subcategories">
            <li> Action
                <ul>
                    <li>Game 1</li>
                    <li>Game 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Movies 
        <ul class="subcategories">
            <li> Fantasy
                <ul>
                    <li>Movie 1</li>
                    <li>Movie 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure doesn't really represents your expected output.
The structure should be something like this:

```
data (object)
    categories (array)
        category (object)
            category name
            subcategories (array)
                subcategory (object)
                    subcategory name
                    items (array)
                        item (object)
                            item name
                            item description
```

Note: I called the innermost array `items` instead of `games/movies/etc`, so it's easier to use it in the template.

You can see my implementation in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/rp11z885/).